# DocuSign auto place do not anchor the tab on the right place

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have c# application that is using DocuSign APIService to sign up documents created in the application.

This is my code for the tab:

```
Tab tab = new Tab();
tab.DocumentID = "1";
tab.RecipientID = "1";
tab.Type = TabTypeCode.SignHere;
tab.AnchorTabItem = new AnchorTab();
//tab.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = "Sign Here (Signer):";
tab.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = string.Format("Sign Here ({0}):", signerName);
tab.AnchorTabItem.IgnoreIfNotPresent = true;
tab.AnchorTabItem.Unit = UnitTypeCode.Pixels;
tab.AnchorTabItem.UnitSpecified = true;
tab.AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 0;
tab.AnchorTabItem.YOffset = 0;
```

This is from DocuSign [documentation](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk/wiki/Code-Walkthrough-_-Anchor-Tabs):

> It does this by finding the bounding box of the anchor text (basically the rectangle containing the text) and using the Lower Right corner of the bounding box as the Lower Left corner of the Tab.

Unfortunately the signature box appears over the anchor text, not after.

I tried the auto place with template - same problem.

Is this a bug or do I do something wrong?

Comment: The documentation link you mentioned is quite old and might not be accurate. See this [link](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs#tab-positioning) for more recent documentation. If no offsets are specified signature box will appear over the anchor text. Also see this [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/#anchoring-tabs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation link you mentioned is quite old and might not be accurate. If no offsets are specified signature box will appear over the anchor text.

See the following for Official Documentation

- [Anchoring Tabs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/#anchoring-tabs)
- [Tab Positioning](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs#tab-positioning)

---

You have couple of options

**Option 1 : Using Anchor Offsets** :

Set the following properties to adjust the location of the anchor tab.

```
tab.AnchorTabItem.Unit = UnitTypeCode.Pixels;
tab.AnchorTabItem.UnitSpecified = true;
tab.AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 0;
tab.AnchorTabItem.YOffset = 0;
```

From [Documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/#anchoring-tabs) :

- **anchorXOffset** : Specifies the X axis location of the tab, in achorUnits, relative to the anchorString.
- **anchorYOffset** : Specifies the Y axis location of the tab, in achorUnits, relative to the anchorString.

---

**Option 2: Using Static Anchor Text**

Another option is add a static anchor text to the document and change the color of the anchor text to white or to the background color of the document.  This way the anchor text does not appear when the document is viewed, making the anchor text invisible to the recipients of the document. More Info [here](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/dfs-user-guide/Content/user-guide/place-automatic-anchor-text-in-document-user.htm)

See more tips and tricks for Anchor Tabs [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/#anchoring-tabs)

Comment: The problem is that my AnchorTabString will be dynamic (updated the code). In this case I don't know what should be the offset.

Comment: The anchor tab will be placed where you tell the code to be placed. You can probably compute the length of your string and build your offsets based on the length. Probably a factor of the Anchor Tab string length.

Comment: From the documentation: "Lower Right corner of the bounding box as the Lower Left corner of the Tab". I expect when I put 0 for both offsets my signature to be placed after the text, not over. I can't calculate the length of the string, because the font can be different size, family, etc...

Comment: Not sure which documentation you are referring to. Can you please post a link to that. Anchor Tabs should be placed over the AnchorText that you specify if no offsets are specified. I have updated my answer with other tips and tricks with Anchor tabs. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: This is the link - https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk/wiki/Code-Walkthrough-_-Anchor-Tabs

Comment: This [documentation](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk/wiki/Code-Walkthrough-_-Anchor-Tabs) is quite old and might no longer be accurate. Did any of the options I suggested work for you.

Comment: I'll try to use the offset and some static text in the document. Where I can find newer documentation?

Comment: See my comments and answer. I have posted links to documentation. Please accept the answer if it addressed your question.